# Tracing Screenshot execution

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, screenshot, analytics

I would really appreciate if someone could explain if its possible or not to receive a notification if a user takes a screenshot on my website? I'm hoping to store this in a database. Perhaps, Analytics.

Post appreciated

Comment: To do that you would have to get outside the browser sandbox, which would be a tremendous security risk. I just don't see that happening.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is if I had a website running is there a way to just receive a notification of some sort that a screen shot was taken? If someone is on their mobile device and looking at my website, wouldn't I be able to log that certain action took place? I would think the website is waiting for other responses from the user. Hopefully this makes sense. I wouldn't need the photo, just an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Since taking a screen shot is a local action that needn't involve the web browser, but just the window manager (or in the extreme case, if one points a camera at the display, not even a bit of the device), a notification is impossible.